# Solving left join issue with multi tables

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have an MySQL situation involving many tables and a left-join and I have problems getting through it !

I'll try to simpify it step by step.

The main task I'm trying to do is joining two tables. The first table contains items and the second one contains actions performed on items. I need every row of the items table to be output (even if no actions were performed on them) so a left join seem to be the solution :

```
select item.ID, count(action.ID) as cnt 
from item 
left join action on action.itemID=item.ID 
group by ID
```

Next step is that I actually need to count only certain type of items. Since I don't need the other types, I filter them out with a where clause.

```
select item.ID, count(action.ID) as cnt 
from item 
left join action on action.itemID=item.ID 
where item.type=3 
group by ID
```

Now things get a bit more complicated. I also need to filter out some items using another table (info). There, I was not sure how to do that. But a simple join and where clause did it.

```
select item.ID, count(action.ID) as cnt 
from (item, info) 
left join action on action.itemID=item.ID 
where item.type=3 and info.itemID=itemID and info.fr is not null 
group by ID
```

So far so good. My query works and the performance is as expected. Now, last thing I need to do is to filter out some actions (not count them) based on another table (subaction). This is where things get really slow and confuse me. I tried this :

```
select item.ID, count(action.ID) as cnt 
from (item, info) 
left join (
           action join subaction on subaction.actionID=action.ID and subaction.type=6
          ) on action.itemID=item.ID 
where item.type=3 and info.itemID=itemID and info.fr is not null 
group by ID
```

At this point, the query suddently slows down by more than 1000 times. I'm obviously doing something wrong !

I tried a simply query that does almost what I need. The only problem is that is doesn't include items that have to matching actions. But I need them too.

```
select item.ID, count(action.ID) as cnt 
from item, info, action, subaction 
where item.type=3 and info.itemID=itemID and info.fr is not null and 
      action.itemID=item.ID subaction.actionID=action.ID and subaction.type=6 
group by ID
```

Anybody has a suggestion as to how to solve such a problem ? Is there a standard way to do that ? Thanks a lot !

**EDIT**

Actually, that last query I submitted is almost what I need : it does not include subqueries, is really performant, makes optimum usage of my indexes, is easy to read, etc.

```
select item.ID, count(action.ID) as cnt 
from item, info, action, subaction 
where item.type=3 and info.itemID=itemID and info.fr is not null and 
      action.itemID=item.ID subaction.actionID=action.ID and subaction.type=6 
group by ID
```

The only tiny thing that does not work is that is does not include item.ID when count(action.ID) is 0.

So I guess my question really is how should I slightly modify the above query so that it also returns item.IDs when count(action.ID) is 0. From what I see, this should not change performances and index usage. Just include those extra item.IDs with 0 as count.

Comment: Have you tried `EXPLAIN`ing the query?

Answer (score 1):

Try joins as below (trying to apply the filter condition first before joining):

```
      SELECT item.ID, count(action.ID) as cnt 
      FROM item JOIN info
           ON (item.type=3 AND info.fr is not null AND info.itemID=item.itemID)
           LEFT JOIN action 
           ON (action.itemID=item.ID)
           JOIN subaction 
           ON (subaction.actionID=action.ID and subaction.type=6)  
      GROUP by item.ID;
```

**EDIT:**

```
      SELECT item.ID, count(action.ID) as cnt 
      FROM item JOIN info
           ON (item.type=3 AND info.fr is not null AND info.itemID=item.itemID)
           LEFT JOIN 
           (select a.* FROM action 
              JOIN subaction 
               ON (subaction.actionID=action.ID and subaction.type=6)) AS act 
           ON (act.itemID=item.ID)
      GROUP by item.ID;
```

Comment: The problem with that is that the last JOIN makes me loose items for which no action exists. In other words, the last JOIN cancels the effects of the LEFT JOIN.

Comment: And if I make the last JOIN a LEFT JOIN as well, I get the right results but performances drop drastically.

Comment: @GillesjrBisson Added another query in the answer. Can you please try and let me know if that helps?

Comment: The second option works just fine but is a bit slower because the subquery makes me loose usage of some indexes. That's why I was trying to avoid subqueries. Is there a way to use indexes even in derived tables ? In this case, the derived table for the second select is a subset of the main one so indexes could in theory be reused...

Comment: @GillesjrBisson I believe doing partitioning in `subaction` table on `type` column should be helpful.